# MeioUpload not creating thumbnails with cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currently using the MeioUpload Plugin located here:

[MeioUpload](https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload)

The file uploading is all working like a charm, but the thumbnails are not being generated.

Has anyone else had this issue?  I am using cakePHP 2.1.

I have followed the readme file strictly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adding this code into the model:

```
class Image extends AppModel {
    var $actsAs = array(
        'MeioUpload.MeioUpload' => array(
            'filename' => array(
                'thumbsizes' => array(
                    '320x90' => array(
                        'width' => 320,
                        'height' => 90
                    )
                )                   
            )
        )
    );

}
```

You can vary the size of the thumbnail with the given parameters above.